# load data from file using script in octave

Tags: matlab, octave

I tried looking online for this and can’t find what I am looking for.  I am trying to write a script to do something I do a lot.  I would like to be able to pass in, as the command argument, the name of a file.  Then my script goes off and plots it the way I want.  So I need to have a character string as the input to the script.  Furthermore I would like to add a check and bail if the input is not a valid character string.

So I want to do something like this… (much appreciated)

```
Function retval = load_3d(filename)       
    retval = 1;
    if( !(filename is character string)) // or better check if it is a CSV file :)
             retval = 0;
             Return;
    Endif

    Bla bla
    .
    .
    . 
endfunction
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the functions `ischar`, `exist` and `csvread`.

```
function status = load_3d (filename)
    status = false;
    if (ischar (filename) &&
        (exist (filename, "file") && ! exist (filename, "dir")))
        status = true;
        data = csvread (filename);
        ## do stuff with data
    endif
endfunction
```

Note that a directory is just a special type of file, so `exist (filename, "file")` will return true for directories.